# Capybara, Chrome Headless: File Download is not working

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, capybara

I am trying to download a file with chrome headless.
My Chrome version is 67.0.3396.87 and my chromedriver has the 2.4.

The file does not appear on my file system. As far as i researched, its a safety function of chrome headless to prevent file downloads, but which can be turned on again.

Thats what i tried to do, regarding to this Thread:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696481

Still nothing works. I tried different approaches with

```
Page.setDownloadBehavior
```

eg. i copied the content of comment 78 but Chrome does not respond to it, or atleast it still does not work:

```
def enable_chrome_headless_downloads(driver, directory)
  bridge = driver.send(:bridge)
  path = '/session/:session_id/chromium/send_command'
  path[':session_id'] = bridge.session_id
  bridge.http.call(:post, path, {
    "cmd" => "Page.setDownloadBehavior",
    "params" => {
      "behavior" => "allow",
      "downloadPath" => directory,
    }
  })
end
```

I also checked if i could download manually a file with headless chrome with

```
'--remote-debugging-port=9222'
```

but it was not possible either.
Has anyone an idea, what I could do to make it work?

Thanks already!

Answer (score 0):

```
Capybara.register_driver :headless_chrome do |app|
  options.add_argument('--headless')
  options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
  options.add_argument('--window-size=1280,800')

  driver = Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome, options: options)

  ### Allow file downloads in Google Chrome when headless!!!
  ### https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696481#c89
  bridge = driver.browser.send(:bridge)

  path = '/session/:session_id/chromium/send_command'
  path[':session_id'] = bridge.session_id

  bridge.http.call(:post, path, cmd: 'Page.setDownloadBehavior',
                                params: {
                                  behavior: 'allow',
                                  downloadPath: '/tmp/downloads'
                                })
  ###

  driver
end
```

full gist
https://gist.github.com/bbonamin/4b01be9ed5dd1bdaf909462ff4fdca95